# Using getJSON in for loop, why do I have to assign a function to hold the value of counter?

Tags: javascript, getjson

Here is the code somebody else posted as a solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
(function(i) { // protects i in an immediately called function
  $.getJSON('/api.php?action=query&list=querypage&qppage=' + array[i] + '&format=json', function (data) {
    $('#' + array[i]).text(data.query.querypage.results.length);
  });
})(i);
}
```

Specifically, what does the (i) do at the end of the function?

Comment: Because it's asynchronous

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: You're passing in the loop index to the IIFE as an argument so it's scoped locally to that function.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. This means that by the time you receive a response from the server and the callback function is executed, the loop will have ended long ago, and `i` will be `array.length-1` for all your calls. To save it for each call, you can use a JS closure like that. (Another name for this specific implementation: IIFE = Immediately-invoked function expression)

Comment: If you use `let` (ES6) instead of `var` you can do away with the IIFE altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, if you don't, the value of `i` will not be as you expect it to be for later function calls. Removing the closure (the `(i)`) will make it always the maximum value for all calls, as they all happen instantaneously (such is the nature of asynchronous programming).

You create a function around this call, then call that function with the value of `i` that you want to preserve the value for when the `getJSON` finishes. Note also, if you were using ES2015, you could use `for(let i = 0; ...)` and it would handle the scoping for you.